# Compiling glibc and adding a function to string.h

Tags: c, linux, makefile, glibc

I have written a simple code called strncat_lh, this is the function:

```
#include <string.h>
int strncat_lh(char *arr1,char *arr2,int n1,int n2)
{

    
    int x=0;
    for(x=0;x<n2;x++)
    {
        *(arr1+n1+x)=arr2[x];
    }
    arr1[x+i+1]='\0';
    return (x+n1+1);
    
    
}
```

So I'd like that the above function becomes part of libc or glibc whichever I am using when import `include <string.h>`. so I want this function to be a part of `string.h`

```
ldd --version
```

says

```
ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.33-0ubuntu5) 2.33
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

I know I need to grab the copy of this from https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/glibc

And I need to compile it and then what. Is this gonna be a single `$: make` command that does the work or what I need to know, please explain. And how to install the output of make or compiled library binary. What binary file name will be and where it can be found is it in the build directory of compiled source?

Please let me know and is there any symbolic link I need to arrange in my system so `gcc program.c` command can find my compile and installed library function `strncat_lh` ? And where exactly I can find the string.h and which source file(s) of `string.h` I will find the place to add above function code? Say If I like to keep the above code in same file as `strlen()`

Comment: This seems to be a naive version of `strncat`? Why would you use it over a well-written and tested standard library function? Why exactly can't you call `strncat` with `array + offset`?

Comment: @Lundin actually as u can see the parameters are bit different. I also have number of other functions I need to add. cant u please just tell

Comment: @user786 if you want to add your own string functions, write your own library and put them there. Modifying a standard library is pointless because you would turn it into a non standard library.

Comment: IMO you would be better off making your own library (or project module).

Comment: @WeatherVane so how to I create symbolic link between gcc to find my library I just want to run command `gcc program.c` and should give me a.out

Comment: Please see [Making a Library](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c15.htm).

Comment: the last comment link is NOT what I am asking. Actually not plan to share the code. So I am not doing anything to which is standard

Comment: on one hand it's not possible unless you want hack\modify your build system toolchain (which needs to be repeated on every compilation machine). You have to  link your library by explicitly doing that in command line. On other hand it's not needed, because there are build tools which `make` it easier

Comment: @user786 modifying glibc is the wrong approach. BTW you'd also need to modify the glibc header files.  It'an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: If you want to contribute new functionality to glibc and want to know how that is done, see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/involved.html . If that's not your goal, as others have said, modifying glibc is not a good idea.

Comment: @user786 I really don't see how it is any different from `strncat(s1+offset, s2, n)` except that the actual `strncat` will have const correctness, restrict pointers and an efficient copy algorithm based on aligned chunks or specific CPU instructions.

Comment: And it would be a lot less work to just write the operation in terms of `strncat()` when you wanted, or at most to create and use a macro that does it.  Creating your own private version of the language to program in would serve you poorly.